# A question about functions in the first-order language

Tags: first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a first-order theory and a set $T$ be the domain of discourse of $L$. Also, let $F$ be a $n$-ary function of $L$.
Then, must the domain of $F$ be $R^n$?
If so, it seems that we can't have diverse functions in algebra.
However,if the $F$'s domain hasn't to be $R^n$, it also quite strange that the rule $\forall x: α\rightarrow α(x/t)$ will sometimes go wrong.
For example, we can obtain $lg(x)+lg(-x)=lg(-x)+lg(x)$ from $\forall x \forall y(x+y=y+x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Assume we have a f-o theory with *language* $L$. We set an *intepretation* with *domain* $D$. If $f$ is an $n$-ary *function symbol* of the language $L$, then YES: the interpretation of $f$ is a function from $D^n$ to $D$.

Comment: Not clear your example... IMO it must be $∀x∀y(x+y=y+x)$. I assume that we are working with the language of f-o *arithmetic* (where the function symbol $+$ is available). If so, and we have a unary function symbo $f$, the quantifier axiom above (UI) give us: $f(x)+f(y)=f(y)+f(x)$.

Comment: Expressing more accurately, if the function's domain is allowed to be a subset of the domain of discourse, then how should we modify the rule "∀x:α→α(x/t)" to avoid the problem?

Comment: Just look at my description of the question, and I think the reason of that contradiction is the domain of logx is R⁺.